# bootstrap modal behaviour issue (react)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, css-transforms

I am using a bootstrap modal for my application. It works fine in the beginning, but once I open the menu bar and close it, modal does not open anymore nor the backdrop does not go away even though I click it.
I have screenshots for better understanding.

1.landing page
[image]

2.testing modal(working)
[image]

3.open side menu bar
[image]

4.after closing the side menu, try opening the modal again(not working)
[image]

To open the menu bar, I use transform: translateX() on body tag so technically the whole body moves side to side to show the menu.
If I comment out the transform: translateX(), modal works fine even after I click the menu bar(it obviously does not show the menu, but other css properties work the same except transform).
So I found out transforming property causes the problem with the modal, but I don't understand why and how to fix it.

EDITTED ( code added ):

```
import 'App.css';

class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.menu_bar = false;
   }

toggleMenu = () => {
    const app = document.querySelector('.App');

    if( this.menu_bar ){
      app.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
      app.classList.remove('coverApp');
      this.menu_bar = false;
    }else {
      app.style.transform = 'translateX(300px)';
      app.classList.add('coverApp');
      this.menu_bar = true;
    }
  }

  hideMenu = (e) => {
    const app = document.querySelector('.App');

    if( e.target.classList.contains('coverApp') ){
      app.style.transform = 'translate(0)';
      app.classList.remove('coverApp');
      this.menu_bar = false;
    }
  }

render() {
  return (
     <div className="App" onClick={this.hideMenu}>
        <Navbar toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}/>
        <LeftMenuBar toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu}/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
function Navbar(props) {

    const { toggleMenu } = props;

    return (
    <nav className="Navbar">
        <span>
            <div id="nav-toggle" onClick={toggleMenu} >&#9776;</div>
            ...
        </span>
    </nav>
    )

}
```

---

```
  function LeftMenuBar(props) {
     const { toggleMenu } = props;

     return (
         <main className="LeftMenuBar">
            <div className="content">
               <div className="controller">
                  <p>ENGLISH</p>
                  <div className="btn-close" onClick={toggleMenu}>CLOSE</div>
                   ...
               </div>
            </div>
         </main>
       )
     }
```

---

```
   class HomePage extends Component {

      render() {
         return (
             <main className="HomePage">
                 <button type="button" id="modal-btn" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#home_modal" aria-label="close">
                LETS START!
                 </button>
                 <div className="HomeModal">
                      <div id="home_modal" className="modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="home_modal">
                           <div className="modal-dialog" role="document" style={{marginTop: '150px', maxWidth: '750px'}}>
                                <div className="modal-content">
                                      <div className="modal-body" style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>...</div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </main>
            )
         }
     }
```

---

CSS

```
   body {
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   .App {
      transition: transform 0.5s;
   }

.coverApp::before {
    content: '';
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 300;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.LeftNavbar {
   position: fixed;
   background: rgba(50, 50, 50);
   color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100vh;
   top: 0;
   left: -300px;
   border-right: solid 0.2px lightgray;
} 

#modal-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 500px;
}

.HomeModal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Please, create an example with code so we can check it. Don't post only images.

Comment: Looks like there is some problem with removing the overlay after closing the menu. But its hard to know without any code examples.